# Execution order in if-else Claus in Scala?

Tags: scala

Here is a simple method and I use it to practice Scala programming , however when pass a empty list as argument, it return false instead of true, which is unreasonable

```
    def test(elem: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    if (elem.isEmpty)
         true
      false
  };
```

I have tried add a "return" at the beginning of line 4， but I also know it is not suggested in Scala. Besieds, Intellij idea gave me a hint 'Unused expression without side effects' if I do not add return. What is the reason under this phenomenon?

Comment: What is `count`?

Comment: @Bergi It dosen't matter and I have modified the code, remove the count variable.

Comment: You don´t need `if` at all here. The function body needs to be just `elem.isEmpty`.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit It is just a  simplied code and need to do something else in the  if clause.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala, the last statement in an expression becomes the return value. Your function consists of 2 statements: 1. `if (list.isEmpty) true` and 2. `false`. Since `false` is the last statement, that will be the return value. The `true` value from the if-test will just be discarded.

To solve it, you need to add `else` to your if-statement, so that the if-statement becomes the only statement (and therefore last) in your function:

```scala
def test(elem: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    if (elem.isEmpty)
        true
    else false
}
```

Or add `return` before `true` (but using `else` is preferred):

```scala
def test(elem: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    if (elem.isEmpty)
        return true
    false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like in Scala , we  should always use else after if.

Comment: Don't use `return` in Scala! It doesn't behave as one might expect.

Comment: @GaëlJ I added a note on it.

Comment: Specifically, the problem is with `return` in lambdas inside other function. `return` doesn't just return locally. https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html